# Counting Numerator and denominator for semi-annual time period

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Hi I have a ocde written for calculating quartely rates. To calculate quarter from the date, I have "YYYYq" in the code. Can anyone help with replacing quarter with semiannual time period. I have tried "YYYY/2" but this didint wowrk. I also tried using "YYYYmm" but that didnt work either.

I want to have numerators and denominators for semiannual period. For eg: if a visit date was 1/1/2012, then this will be counted in first half of the year. All vists dates from 1/1/2012 - 06/30/2012 will get couonted in the first semiannual period and from 6/30/2012 - 12/31/2012 will be counted in second semiannual time period.

Thanks so much for your time and suggestions.

```
   Function Visits(target_timeframe)

        Target_Quarter = Format(target_timeframe, "YYYYq")

        For vRow = 2 To 2000

            entered_timeframe = Format(Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & vRow).Value, "YYYYq")

            Entered_Visits = Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & vRow).Value 'equals value of column

            If (entered_timeframe = Target_Quarter) Then
                denominator = denominator + 1
                If (Entered_Visits > 0) Then
                    numerator = numerator + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next

        If denominator > 0 Then
            Average = numerator / denominator
        Else
            Average = "N/A"
        End If

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

test the "q" part of the format to see if it is 1 or 2, and set the string accordingly.

```
Target_Half = Format(target_timeframe, "YYYY") & _
     IIf(Format(target_timeframe, "q") <= "2", "/1", "/2")
```

this will make the `Target_Half` to be `YYYY/1` for the first half of the year and `YYYY/2` for the second half

Comment: LOL @Sean, didn't see yours as I was typing mine.  Nice answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no custom date format for half-years, so you'll have to build the string yourself.  Replace the first line in the function with:

```
Target_Quarter = Year(target_timeframe) & IIf(Month(target_timeframe) <= 6, 1, 2)
```

You will have to do something similar with the first line within the loop.